# SwipeRefreshLayout is turning so fast for a few seconds

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

When it fails to load data from API, I am showing an Error View and hiding `SwipeRefreshLayout`:

```
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("refreshing")
    fun setSwipeRefreshLayout(view: SwipeRefreshLayout, resource: Resource<List<SavingsGoal>>?) {
        view.visibility = if (resource is Resource.Failure) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
        view.isRefreshing = resource is Resource.Loading || resource is Resource.Reloading
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("showError")
    fun showError(view: View, resource: Resource<List<SavingsGoal>>?) {
        view.visibility = if (resource is Resource.Failure) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
```

When I'm clicking on Retry button in Error View, `load` function get called from ViewModel :

```
fun load() {
     _liveData.postValue(Resource.Loading())
     showSavingsGoals()
}
```

What is strange is that `SwipeRefreshLayout` is turning so fast for a few seconds. I cannot figure out what is the reason. I appreciate it if you can help out.

Answer (score 1):

it may happen if you call refresh when it is already refreshing. check if you call it more than once

Comment: Thank you @Hooman, I created an issue in Google issue tracker for further investigation : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147873054